# Which spells are currently available to safeguard a fixed location?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, defense

After reading [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147877/is-there-a-spell-to-protect-inanimate-objects/147882#147882) on how to safeguard an inanimate item, and thinking back on [this question of mine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123681/how-can-maximum-protection-for-a-clone-stored-in-a-demiplane-be-achieved), which was closed as too broad, I still think a list of spells that allow creating a very defensible location would be beneficial - I've checked back on that question of mine more than once, but I'm not sure it's 100% complete.

Anyways, to limit the scope of this question, here are my criteria:

- the spell is either permanent by default (such as [Hallow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow)) or can be made permanent by casting it repeatedly in the same spot (such as [Forbiddance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forbiddance))
- the spell has either

  - a detrimental effect on all creatures, specific creatures or specific creature types or ...
  - a beneficial effect on specific (not all!) creatures or creature types
- the spell does **not** create or is related to minions (such as *Finger of Death* for undead guardians, *Simulacrum*, or Geas'd hirelings.
- terrain shaping spells are not within the scope of this question either, even if they can be creatively used to defend a location.
- this question is limited to spells. Magical objects or mundane traps, useful as they might be, are therefore not within the scope of this question, either.

Since this should result in a very limited list of spells (no more than I dozen, I'd wager) which is comparatively easy to maintain as new rulebooks come out, I don't believe this question should be considered off-topic, as per this [meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/what-are-list-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The following spells are available:

- *[Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding)*
- *[Symbol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol)*
- *[Guards and Wards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guards-and-wards)*
- *[Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/private-sanctum)*
- *[Forbiddance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forbiddance)*
- *[Hallow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow)*
- *[Druid Grove](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/druid-grove)*
- *[Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)*: to save costs on material components or to use it in a stress-inducing way

Comment: I made this a community wiki because I don't want to gain any further reputation by posting a subset of a previous answer of mine. Also, any other answers would have to reference this answer or duplicate its content if they aim to be complete, and I think it's better to just have one answer that can be modified to completition.